# Users with short names (2 characters excluding spaces) can't be pinged by mentions in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Users such as [T J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333214/t-j) cannot be mentioned in chat.
Replies work `:(TJ_message_id) reply`, but simple mentions `@TJ` do not.

There is no ping, hovering on the message has no effect when it should highlight the last message of mentioned user, and there is no on-site notification.

[image: Screenshot of TJ's mention]

This might be linked to the fact that mentions with 2 characters simply don't work. Trying to mention someone named `foobar` with `@fo` will not work even if there is no ambiguity in who the mention is aimed at (there is no other user in the room whose name starts with `fo`).

Comment: I'd guess it because that's not his **actual** user name in the database...its " t-j " for pinging purposes I think. Hover over his name and you can see it in the link bar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: What if users change their name on purpose so that they can't be pinged? :P

Comment: [Huh?!](http://i.imgur.com/xUTrQUX.png) ... wait... I'm a man... and I can't ping those users... Therefore it must be true! Ladies, can you confirm?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Hah, you beat me to it

Comment: 123879459876987425245 years later > Still waiting for a comment from Ladies :P

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett [Called it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30583640#30583640)!

Comment: In before meta post titled "*Mid-word truncation can lead to minor confusion with long tit...[les on the hot meta board]*".

Comment: OMG a world of new trolling possibilities has just revealed itself to me!!!

Comment: This happened to me as my name is SO as  `M D` and in chat room it shows as `MD` while in comment it shows right `M D`

Comment: Can confirm. I'm a floating smiley, and even _I_ can't ping those users.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Your capability of predicting the future is impressive: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323183/2675154.

Comment: Maybe set the minimal length of a name should be the way.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I think people are free to be not pingable, and it's reasonable to not allow 2-letter pings (due to ambiguity). We just need a clear warning that you'll lose pinging privileges with a short username.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett An old and yet still funny trick. http://imgur.com/a/648ht

Comment: This was reported on mSE several years ago - no response though: [Chat not pinging when name is too short](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191884/chat-not-pinging-when-name-is-too-short)

Comment: @Kyll I beg to differ. The behaviour you're describing corresponds to comments on the main site, but chat is different: everybody who matches will be pinged. Compare [this screenshot courtesy of Ander Biguri](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gboAa.png) with the transcript [around here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30610834#30610834): both Ander and I were pinged by @​And.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Are you really going to sell a bug as a feature? :-D There should *definitely* be a warning, yes: because it is a very surprising behavior, and the user in question may never even realize... only others will notice. Being unmentional would be a separate feature (checkbox?) --- if it is useful at all

Comment: @jpaugh for some reason I was under the impression that *any* ping only works above 3 characters inclusive. Up until this meta post, due to which I did some investigation and realized that 2-char pings (should?) work in comments on the sites. So, while I accept that this might not be by design, I do admit that I still half imagine this to have some reason behind it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Fair enough.

Comment: Relax everybody. I'm taking a look at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed: as of now, users whose normalized name consists of just two characters can be pinged in chat.

Comment: What about 1 character now? :D

Comment: @Tunaki The target for that one is at most 26 users, so how about no ;-)