# Mid-word truncation results in confusing titles on meta's "hot" board

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, community-bulletin

I got a laugh out of this one this morning.

[image]

The problem is the truncation of the word "mentions" into "men." Hovering shows the full text.

The fix is truncate on word boundaries. And curiously, about this case, the truncation isn't even needed at that spot.

Comment: ["The code around community bulletin is ...historical and needs some rewrite love. In fact the logic is quite convoluted and hard to explain."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314403/792066)

Comment: Truncated text length = 80. May be useless fact. May be useful information to someone

Comment: Love your edit on my title

Comment: @PaulCezanne: Well, but still 8 characters too long...

Comment: @DavidG Originally I tried adding three dots but they silently get removed, though it allows a proper ellipsis. Maybe Braiam fell foul of that.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's a proper ellipsis on the cb, I'd have been disappointed it it wasn't in the title too...

Comment: You got a laugh? Well I got **triggered**.

Comment: We should improve this, as removing the end of a sentence is high-value information.  Instead, we should remove characters from the middle of the sentence in a uniform manner, thus spreading out the loss of information over less critical parts of the sentence.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323174/users-with-short-names-2-characters-excluding-spaces-cant-be-pinged-by-mentio#comment344904_323174

Comment: In case they have any problems implementing this: [Truncate string on whole words in .NET C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1613896/3853934)

Comment: @Yakk Good idea, though we would have to be careful with that kind of implementation or else we could end up with "Users with short...characters...can't be pinged by men...in chat" or maybe "Users with short...s ...can't be pinged by men..."

Comment: @KevinWells I figure we can use a dictionary and grammar checking engine to ensure that, as best we can, after removing parts of the sentence, we still end up with a grammarically correct sentence with well spelled words.  That should reduce confusion by maximizing information flow.

Comment: @Yakk Well "Users with shorts can't be pinged by men" is a grammatically correct sentence, it just doesn't mean what the original title meant (and really I was just joking about the funny possibilities of that kind of algorithm)

Comment: @KevinWells We cannot expect perfect fidelity when removing characters from a sentence.

Comment: @Yakk seems the obvious solution would be to auto-txt-spk: "usrs w sht names (2chars w/o space) Cnot b pinged by mentN n cht lol". I'm led to believe from "dem yooth" that it's still perfectly readable with zero information loss.

Comment: @Dave I think dem yooth would want some emojis in there.

Comment: Should we move this question to meta.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @PaulCezanne It would be turtles all the way up...

Comment: Current title of THIS meta post is also [truncated at a funny point](http://imgur.com/vqRF782)... :D

Comment: @anishsane: Yes, that was intentional.

Comment: ^^ Yes, sure... I liked the precision...

Comment: @Yakk ohhh, Shannon would be so proud of you. Remove content while maintaining the information level of the title. Entropy FTW!

Comment: @BoltClock: [Your comment should be flagged and deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279263/155739). \*ducks\*

Comment: Simple solution: just find the most frequent 127 words in SO titles, assign a 1-byte code to each (leading bit=1), and set all other characters to byte value of most-similar-ASCII-character.  Publish this list, post titles raw hex representation of this encoding, and have everyone use a simple browser skin to expand and display the actual title (snipped at 80 characters for brevity).  Simple, elegant, and totally solves the problem.

Comment: @Braiam Wasn't that before ellipses were added though?, it's obviously been modified since.

Comment: @Lankymart not sure what you are talking about..

Comment: @Braiam Don't matter... You highlighted [this URL](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314403/792066) in relation to the question, but it's nearly 6 months old, how long have ellipses *(`...`)* been displayed on Community Bulletins was what I was referring to.

Comment: @Lankymart my point was that the CB code is old and weird and old, so there may be nobody that can sensibly fix this.

Comment: I rolled back the title to the longer, more descriptive, and more demonstrative version.

Comment: ... Which goes against the OP's apparent intentions, @bjb568. I don't want to get involved in that edit war, but I'm very tempted to roll it back to the OP's original revision.

Comment: It's a better title so it should stay. This is meta, extensive editing is the norm.

Comment: Correction: _"This is meta, [we hate fun](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55ac76aae4b08d4c252270d0/t/55b071c0e4b08861c79e6e13/1437626817203/grumpy-cat-i-had-fun-once)"_. The title was clever, and clear enough once you take a quick look at the question.

Comment: Fun aside, this title is functionally and objectively better. "Hating fun" doesn't mean we need to impose worse titles on questions.

Comment: Well then, at least let's mangle the title _properly_, then. I removed redundant content. Titles won't be truncated if they're not "long". "long" is redundant. The title also doesn't need to mention "title" twice.

Answer (score 18):

I just modified the truncation function used so that if a word gets cut in half, it is removed from the result. So in the case in point the result would be *Users with short names (2 characters excluding spaces) can not be pinged by...*

Answer (score 4):

A simple possible solution is to truncate to full words.